# SSRS Substracing Date returns False for valid If Statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, reportingservices-2005

When the condition is satisfied, below query prints out

[image]

instead of a date selected -1 day, however it does display the selected date when conditions are not met.

[image]

```
=IIF(Parameters!subscription.Value =0 AND Parameters!shiftId.Value = "Shift 3", Parameters!date.Value =DateAdd("d", -1, Parameters!date.Value), Parameters!date.Value)
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the second argument of the `IIF` statement:

`Parameters!date.Value =DateAdd("d", -1, Parameters!date.Value)`

Which is doing a comparison between two values, and hence returning a boolean value.

All you need is the `DateAdd` part of this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!subscription.Value =0 AND Parameters!shiftId.Value = "Shift 3"
  , DateAdd("d", -1, Parameters!date.Value)
  , Parameters!date.Value)
```

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you very much!